# Animation in React Native triggered by onPress not displaying animations immediately on screen load in Android only

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, animation

I'm getting a behaviour I wasn't expecting in my React Native project using Animation.View on Android.

React-native 0.72

I'm loading a screen `MyProfile` and showing up user's info and badges. When I press on a badge it opens a `Popup` component that displays as children a `BadgePopUp` component that displays badge's info with multiple animations for each element.

It works nice except if I press on the badge immediately when badges are shown (page might still be loading). By using console.logs I see that it waits for page to fully load and then launches the pop up thus creating a slight delay.

I'm ok with it but the problem is it opens the pop up all blank then after the timing of the animations it shows the items without the animations (sometimes only the badge img is delayed). Then if I close it and press it again, or if on screen load I wait a coupla seconds before I press on it, it works fine.

This does not happen in ios, only in android, and only in this page, not in the rest of the screens.

My implementation:

MyProfile.js:

```
...
const MyProfile = () => {
  const { user, favoriteCourts, addedCourts, badges } = useSelector(
    state => state.userReducer,
  );

  ...

  const verifiedBadges = JSON.parse(Storage.getString('badges'));
  const getVerifiedBadge = badgeId => {
    const badge = verifiedBadges?.find(item => item.id === badgeId);
    return badge;
  };
  const badge = getVerifiedBadge(user?.user_badge_id);

  ...

  const [isPopUpVisible, setIsPopUpVisible] = useState(false);
  const [highestLevelBadges, setHighestLevelBadges] = useState(
    getHighestLevelBadges(badges),
  );
  const [badgeDetailsToDisplay, setBadgeDetailsDataToDisplay] = useState(null);

  ...

  const handleMyBadges = () => {
    navigation.navigate('MyBadges');
  };

  const handleBadgeDetails = (
    badgeLevel,
    badgeImg,
    badgeName,
    badgeQuantity,
    badgeDescription,
  ) => {
    setBadgeDetailsDataToDisplay({
      badgeLevel: badgeLevel,
      badgeImg: badgeImg,
      badgeName: badgeName,
      badgeQuantity: badgeQuantity,
      badgeDescription: badgeDescription,
    });

    setIsPopUpVisible(true);
  };

  const getBadgeQuantityText = actionName => {
    switch (actionName) {
      case 'court_registrations':
        return `${addedCourts?.length} ${t('Court_hunter_add_info')}`;
        break;
      case 'court_checkins':
        return `${user?.num_checkins} ${t('King_of_the_court_add_info')}`;
        break;
      default:
        return t('Court_hunter_add_info');
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleBadgesToDisplay = () => {
    badgesToDisplay = highestLevelBadges.map((badge, index) => {
      const badgeImageSource = gatBadgeImage(badge.id);

      const badgeLevel = getBadgeLevelName(badge.options.level);
      const badgeName =
        badge.options.action_name === 'court_registrations'
          ? t('Court_hunter')
          : badge.name.split(' - ', 1);
      const badgeQuantity = getBadgeQuantityText(badge.options.action_name);
      const badgeDescription =
        lang !== 'en-US' ? badge.description : badge.description_en;

      return (
        <View key={index} style={{ left: 4, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
          <ContainedImage
            image={badgeImageSource}
            size={'extra-small'}
            action={() => {
              console.log('pressed on badge');
              handleBadgeDetails(
                badgeLevel,
                badgeImageSource,
                badgeName,
                badgeQuantity,
                badgeDescription,
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    });

    return badgesToDisplay;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('isFocused, navigationState');

    const scrollIfNeeded = () => {
      if (scrollViewRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
      }
    };

    // Get the current screen's route key
    const currentRouteKey = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index].key;

    // Check if the tab is focused and the current screen is the starting screen
    const isTabFocused = isFocused && currentRouteKey === 'StartingScreen';

    if (isTabFocused) {
      scrollIfNeeded();
    }
  }, [isFocused, navigationState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in addedCourts, favoriteCourts useEffect');
    if (addedCourts !== null && favoriteCourts !== null && user !== null) {
      setFavCourtsToSend(favoriteCourts);
      handleGetMyEvents();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [addedCourts, favoriteCourts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in events and filteredEvents useEffect');
    if (events && !filteredEvents) {
      setFilteredEvents(filterEventsByDate(events));
    }
  }, [events, filteredEvents]);

  return (
    <FullContainer
      header={true}
      hasActions={true}
      logo={true}
      hasBackButton={false}
      hideSearch={true}
      hideAddCourt={true}
      showConfig={true}
      hasNotifications={true}>
      {isPageLoading && <LoaderView />}
      {isPopUpVisible === true && badgeDetailsToDisplay !== null && (
        <PopUp
          visible={isPopUpVisible}
          onClose={() => {
            setIsPopUpVisible(false);
          }}
          fixedHeight={true}
          hasDarkTransparency={true}>
          <BadgePopUp
            title={badgeDetailsToDisplay.badgeName}
            image={badgeDetailsToDisplay.badgeImg}
            badgeName={badgeDetailsToDisplay.badgeLevel}
            additionalInfo={badgeDetailsToDisplay.badgeQuantity}
            description={badgeDetailsToDisplay.badgeDescription}
            hasAnimations={true}
          />
        </PopUp>
      )}
      <AlertModal
        modalVisible={modalVisible}
        setModalVisible={setModalVisible}
        title={modalTitle}
        text={modalText}
        hasCloseButton={true}
      />
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        style={[{ paddingHorizontal: 0 }, Styles.flexOne]}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View
          style={[
            ProfilePageStyles.profileInfoContainer,
            ProfilePageStyles.paddingPage,
          ]}>
          <Text style={ProfilePageStyles.title}>{t('tab_profile')}</Text>
          <View style={ProfilePageStyles.profileHeaderContainer}>
            <View style={ProfilePageStyles.boxPicture}>
              <CircleDisplay
                size={'small'}
                pressable={false}
                type={'image'}
                src={user?.picture_url}
                colorType={'grey'}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={ProfilePageStyles.boxSocialBar}>
              <SocialBar
                checkins={user?.num_checkins}
                followers={user?.num_followers}
                following={user?.num_following}
                onPress={handleGoToFollowersPage}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={Styles.flexRow}>
            <Text style={ProfilePageStyles.labelBold}>
              {user?.first_name} {user?.last_name}
            </Text>
            {user?.user_badge_id && (
              <Pressable
                onPress={() => {
                  handleToast(
                    lang === 'en-US' ? badge.description_en : badge.description,
                    badge.name,
                    'gray',
                  );
                }}
                style={[
                  ProfilePageStyles.badgePressable,
                  { backgroundColor: badge?.hex_color },
                ]}>
                <Text style={ProfilePageStyles.badgeText}>{badge?.name}</Text>
              </Pressable>
            )}
          </View>

          <Text style={ProfilePageStyles.labelRegular}>@{user?.username}</Text>

          <Text style={[ProfilePageStyles.labelRegular, { marginTop: 6 }]}>
            {user?.profile_info}
          </Text>
          <View style={ProfilePageStyles.profileEditContainer}>
            <HoopersButton
              size={'small'}
              theme1={'primary'}
              onPress1={() => {
                handleEditProfile();
              }}
              text1={t('Edit_profile')}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{ paddingBottom: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.HPS_WHITE }}>
          <View
            style={[
              Styles.alignDisplayFlexRow,
              Styles.rowStartCenter,
              ProfilePageStyles.paddingPage,
            ]}>
            <Text style={[ProfilePageStyles.labelBold, { marginRight: 8 }]}>
              {t('My_badges')}
            </Text>
            <HoopersButton
              size={'tiny'}
              theme1={'outline'}
              onPress1={() => {
                handleMyBadges();
              }}
              text1={t('See_all')}
            />
          </View>
          {badges.length > 0 ? (
            <View style={[Styles.alignDisplayFlexRow, Styles.rowStartCenter]}>
              <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                style={{ width: width, marginTop: 13 }}>
                {handleBadgesToDisplay()}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          ) : (
            <View style={[Styles.center, { marginTop: 13 }]}>
              <Text style={ProfilePageStyles.labelRegular}>
                {t('User_has_no_badges')}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>

        <View style={ProfilePageStyles.profileCourtsContainer}>
          {isLoading && <LoaderView color={Colors.HPS_OFWHITE} />}
          {!isLoading && renderAddedCourtsSection()}
          {!isLoading && renderFavoriteCourtsSection()}
          {!isLoading && filteredEvents && renderEventsSection()}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </FullContainer>
  );
};

export default MyProfile;
```

PopUp.js:

```
...
const PopUp = ({
  onClose,
  children,
  visible,
  fixedHeight,
  hasDarkTransparency,
  hasConfettis,
}) => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  const confettiRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visible && hasConfettis && confettiRef.current) {
      confettiRef.current.start();
    }
  }, [visible]);

  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="fade"
      transparent={true}
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={onClose}>
      <View
        style={[
          PopUpStyles.container,
          hasDarkTransparency
            ? {
                backgroundColor: Colors.darkTransparency,
              }
            : {
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightTransparency,
              },
        ]}>
        <View
          style={[
            PopUpStyles.secondContainer,
            { width: width },
            fixedHeight === true && { height: height * 0.8, maxHeight: 600 },
          ]}>
          <View
            style={[
              PopUpStyles.popup,
              {
                width: width * 0.85,
                maxWidth: 400,
              },
            ]}>
            <Pressable
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                zIndex: 99,
                right: -10,
                top: -10,
              }}
              onPress={onClose}>
              <Icon
                name="closeCircle"
                width="30"
                height="30"
                fill={Colors.HPS_ORANGE}
                stroke={Colors.HPS_GREY}
              />
            </Pressable>
            {children}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      {hasConfettis && (
        <ConfettiCannon
          ref={confettiRef}
          count={120} // Number of confetti particles
          origin={{ x: -10, y: 0 }} // Starting position (in this case, bottom-left corner)
          autoStart={true} // Don't auto-start confetti, start it manually after other animations
          fadeOut={true} // Make confetti fade out after some time
        />
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default PopUp;
```

BadgePopUp.js:

```
const BadgePopUp = ({
  title,
  subtitle,
  image,
  badgeName,
  additionalInfo,
  description,
  action,
  hasAnimations,
}) => {
  console.log('BadgePopUp: Rendering component');
  
  ...

  const spinValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0.01)).current;
  const scaleValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(2.5)).current;
  const laterOpacityAnimValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0.01)).current;
  const firstOpacityAnimValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0.01)).current;
  const slideDownValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(-70)).current;
  const slideRightValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(-200)).current;
  const slideLeftValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(200)).current;

  const setAnimation = (toValue, duration, easing, useNativeDriver) => {
    return {
      toValue: toValue,
      duration: duration,
      easing: easing,
      useNativeDriver: useNativeDriver,
    };
  };

  const renderImage = () => {
    return <Image source={image} width={130} height={130} />;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasAnimations === true && image) {
      Animated.parallel([
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.delay(100),
          Animated.timing(firstOpacityAnimValue, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 500,
            easing: Easing.ease,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }),
        ]),
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.delay(200),
          Animated.timing(laterOpacityAnimValue, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 350,
            easing: Easing.ease,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }),
        ]),
        Animated.timing(spinValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(slideDownValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 350,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(slideRightValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(slideLeftValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]).start(() => {
        console.log('BadgePopUp: Animations completed');
      });
    }
  }, [
    spinValue,
    scaleValue,
    laterOpacityAnimValue,
    firstOpacityAnimValue,
    slideDownValue,
    slideRightValue,
    slideLeftValue,
    hasAnimations,
    image,
  ]);

  const spin = spinValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
  });

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={[
          BadgePopUpStyles.container,
          {
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
            maxHeight: propsVol > 5 ? 500 : 400,
          },
        ]}>
        {title && (
          <View style={BadgePopUpStyles.titleContainer}>
            {hasAnimations === true ? (
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  transform: [{ translateY: slideDownValue }],
                  opacity: firstOpacityAnimValue,
                }}>
                <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.title}>{title}</Text>
              </Animated.View>
            ) : (
              <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.title}>{title}</Text>
            )}
          </View>
        )}
        {subtitle && (
          <View style={BadgePopUpStyles.subtitleContainer}>
            {hasAnimations === true ? (
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  transform: [{ translateX: slideRightValue }],
                  opacity: laterOpacityAnimValue,
                }}>
                <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</Text>
              </Animated.View>
            ) : (
              <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</Text>
            )}
          </View>
        )}
        {image && (
          <>
            {hasAnimations === true ? (
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  transform: [{ rotate: spin }, { scale: scaleValue }],
                  opacity: laterOpacityAnimValue,
                }}>
                <View style={BadgePopUpStyles.imageContainer}>
                  {renderImage()}
                </View>
              </Animated.View>
            ) : (
              <View style={BadgePopUpStyles.imageContainer}>
                {renderImage()}
              </View>
            )}
          </>
        )}
        {(badgeName || additionalInfo) && (
          <View style={BadgePopUpStyles.badgeContainer}>
            {badgeName &&
              (hasAnimations === true ? (
                <Animated.View
                  style={{
                    transform: [{ translateX: slideRightValue }],
                    opacity: laterOpacityAnimValue, // Apply opacity animation to ContainedImage
                  }}>
                  <Text
                    style={[BadgePopUpStyles.subtitle, { marginBottom: 5 }]}>
                    {badgeName}
                  </Text>
                </Animated.View>
              ) : (
                <Text style={[BadgePopUpStyles.subtitle, { marginBottom: 5 }]}>
                  {badgeName}
                </Text>
              ))}
            {additionalInfo &&
              (hasAnimations === true ? (
                <Animated.View
                  style={{
                    transform: [{ translateX: slideLeftValue }],
                    opacity: laterOpacityAnimValue,
                  }}>
                  <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.description}>
                    {additionalInfo}
                  </Text>
                </Animated.View>
              ) : (
                <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.description}>
                  {additionalInfo}
                </Text>
              ))}
          </View>
        )}

        {description && (
          <View style={BadgePopUpStyles.descriptionContainer}>
            {hasAnimations === true ? (
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  transform: [{ translateX: slideRightValue }],
                  opacity: laterOpacityAnimValue,
                }}>
                <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.description}>{description}</Text>
              </Animated.View>
            ) : (
              <Text style={BadgePopUpStyles.description}>{description}</Text>
            )}
          </View>
        )}

        {action &&
          (hasAnimations === true ? (
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                opacity: laterOpacityAnimValue,
              }}>
              <TextLink
                text={action.title ? action.title : 'See more'}
                type={'orange'}
                size={16}
                onPress={action.onPress}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          ) : (
            <TextLink
              text={action.title ? action.title : 'See more'}
              type={'orange'}
              size={16}
              onPress={action.onPress}
            />
          ))}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default BadgePopUp;
```

Any idea why this might be happening?